# In what branch of science does technology belong?

Tags: computer-history

The question may be found in the following link. I have been asked in the comments to provide my question on this Stack Exchange site.

*[Is there a word for mathematics/physics/data-analytics/…?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536469/is-there-a-word-for-mathematics-physics-data-analytics)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, technology *per se* isn't science. But then, neither is mathematics. Technology is normally about the creation of things. Science is about using a certain methodology for trying to discern the truth about the world and natural processes. If you define natural processes broadly, including human processes, then social science is also science.

But mathematics is about using logical process to explore the implications of basic assumptions (axioms).

But both science and mathematics are about *ideas*, whereas technology is about *things*.

Technology, as in iPhones and respirators and all, is about the creation of useful things. That is basically why you can *patent* inventions, but you can only copyright scientific papers.

Some sorts of technology, say vaccines, depend on science to assure safety and efficacy. And some sorts of technology depend on mathematics, such as computers and bitcoin.

Computer Science has elements of both science and technology. But one normally gets a PhD in CS for discoveries on the scientific side, even if the science is an exploration of something created on the technological side. CS actually has elements of mathematics as well, such as in algorithm analysis and computability theory.

Comment: That's a very nice explanation thanks a lot @Buffy.

Comment: But computer science is neither about computers nor science... There is a reason Naur objected to the term.

Comment: Computer technology could be considered *applied* computer science.

Answer (score 4):

Science is theory and Technology is putting science into implementation.
Science is like learning swimming by seeing youtube and Technology is diving into a water body and swimming yourself.
So my dear Technology is not a branch of science, but itself technology is practical implementation or practical ways of implementation.

Comment: I think that if you look up "technology" in a dictionary, you won't find much mention of "science." Technology studies the _techniques_ that we use to make things. Some of those techniques may be inspired by science (i.e., the result of "applied science,") but that's not what the "technology" label implies. Hand built pottery, and hand-woven fabrics are just as "technological" as are computers and nuclear power stations.

Comment: Is “my dear” addressing the poster or qualifying technology? Seems like it may be a bit misplaced and could be removed

Comment: Someone tries to be nice or polite and someone objects.